# Can I access a command interaction from a separate file in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I have a discord bot with a command that runs a separate script and then follows up with a 'done' message. The response has to be from the separate script.

I have tried saving the interaction variable from the command file to a temporary file, and then reading from it in the file the command runs, but it doesn't have any of the response functions. Is there a way to 'reconstruct' the interaction and regain those functions?

Code:

`const tempFileContent = fs.readFileSync('./temp.json', 'utf8'); const jsonData = JSON.parse(tempFileContent); jsonData.restartMsg.followUp('test');`

Error:

`jsonData.restartMsg.followUp is not a function TypeError: jsonData.restartMsg.followUp is not a function`

Is there a way to add back the functions? I'm using discord.js v14.14.1 and node v20.9.0

Comment: Can you show your code? Explain what is wrong and then explain what should happen.

Comment: @Liam I edited the post to clarify and added code

Comment: Need to see more code than that, cant tell anything about how the program works from one line, not trying to be pedantic, just not too sure how I can help without the full context haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a new instance of the class and move the data of the old instance from the file to the new instance.

The methods missing in the file (JSON format does not store functions) would be included in the new class instance.